# Why do texts with non-ASCII characters have right padding?

Tags: html, margin, graphviz, non-ascii-characters

If you look at the image below, you will see that if the text has non-ASCII characters it is pushed away from the right margin, and if it has emoji it is pushed closer to the margin. Do you know why is that?

[image]

Here is the code

```
graph {
    node [shape=plain]

A [label=<
<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>Text with ASCII characters only</td></tr>
</table>>];

B [label=<
<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>Text with non-ASCII charắcters</td></tr>
</table>>];

C [label=<
<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>Text with emoji  very funny hahahahaha</td></tr>
</table>>];
}
```

Comment: Most likely due to a small problem in the calculation of the width of the characters.

Comment: Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Nope, but maybe post a message with graphviz on gitlab as well.

Comment: The emoji-text is actually correctly center-aligned (all three labels are), it's just that the cell width is less than text width. This can be better seen when settting `width="300"` for the `td`s. However, as you demonstrated, there is a problem with the width calculation of texts using diacritics (middle cell), but I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: @marapet for the emoji text, isn't that the cell width should span to fit the text? Anyway, I open this issue [in Graphviz's GitLab](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2079#related-issues)

Comment: I also have the same problem, graphviz tells me that: `Warning: no value for width of non-ASCII character 226. Falling back to width of space character`. Don't know how to fix.

Comment: @Tropilio I asked this on [Graphviz's repo](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2079#note_583978513) and the answer is that this is a PangoCairo issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's thread on [Graphviz repo](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2079#note_583978513) guided me in the right direction. This is what I've done to fix the problem:

- Install expat library (`sudo apt install libexpat1-dev`)
- Install pangocairo library (`sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev`)
- Compile and install graphviz from source (https://graphviz.org/download/source/):

  ```
  ./configure --with-pangocairo
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

Now everything works as expected (non-ASCII characters are in the right place), plus `pdf` output is now available!

Answer (score 0):

I asked this on [Graphviz's repo](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2079#note_583978513) and the answer is that this is a PangoCairo issue.